# Fail-safe way of round-tripping Flash swf files to text-representation and back

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, reverse-engineering

I'm looking for a fail-safe way to round-trip between a Flash swf file and a text representation and back again.

One strict requirement is that the resulting round-tripped Flash swf file is exactly functionally equivalent to the original Flash swf file as long as the text representation is left unchanged.

Furthermore, the text representation must be human-readable and editable. It should be possible to make small changes to the the text representation (such as changing a text string or a class name, etc.) which are reflected in the resulting class file representation.

Is there a fail-safe way to achieve Flash swf file/text-representation/Flash swf file round-tripping given the requirements above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is [swfmill](http://swfmill.org/) not failsafe?

that's really **the** tool for what you want to do ...

other than that, i can only suggest learning [Haxe](http://haxe.org), and using [hxformat](http://code.google.com/p/hxformat/) to read the SWF and convert it to whatever kind of text representation you want ...

Comment: +1 since swfmill is meant to do exactly what was asked for. However, even it fails on some SWF v8 files (which it's supposed to support). Do you know whether there are better tools now, 2 years later?

Comment: Also, could you explain how you'd use hxformat for this? Based on a quick look at its website, it looks like just an image/animation format library, rather than a full swf translator.

Comment: @Mechanical snail: First, convert the SWF into [data structures](http://code.google.com/p/hxformat/source/browse/trunk/format/swf/Data.hx). This will give you a complete representation of the SWF. Thereafter you can use the abc reader to transform the binary blocks of actionscript into [data structures](http://code.google.com/p/hxformat/source/browse/trunk/format/abc/Data.hx) in case that's what you want.